# Separating comma delimited data from one cell to multiple cells when the entry is a live data link

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, csv

My Excel model imports live data from some trading software. If I insert the following formula, I get the details of current tender offers, which are constantly changing:

```
=RTD("rit2.rtd",, "tenderinfo", "1")
```

However, this data is displayed as follows when available, before returning to a blank cell once the tender expires:

```
4020, RETC, 23401, 2910
```

Basically it's a list of data related to one deal in one cell, separated by commas.

I need to separate each value into a separate cell so that I can use them in equations. I'm not sure if I can use the "text to columns" function in Excel since the contents of the cell is a link, which temporarily shows the current tender offer data until it expires.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Yes you are write that Text to column can't be used since it spoils the Formula itself. But you can use the Formula I've suggested it's working  successfully on the Formula Cell also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the text functions Left(), Mid() and Right() to extract the data from the cell, even if the cell itself contains a formula. The text functions will look at the result of the formula and can parse the text.

The exact parameters of the formulas will depend on the data. For example, if the first value is always four digits, you can simply use

```
=Left(A1),4)
```

but if the first value can have fewer or more digits, then you may need to look for the position of the first comma and extract text before the first comma:

```
=Left(A1,Find(",",A1)-1)
```

The other formulas will follow a similar approach.

If you don't want to do this with formulas, you could use VBA to copy the cell contents to another place and then parse it with Text to Columns.

Comment: Hey Teylyn, the second formula seems like it would work since the amount of digits in each number will vary. I have managed to use that formula to get the number before the first comma. If I have 3 numbers separated with commas I can just use the left,mid and right functions. What if I have 5 or 6 values separated by commas? I can still get the left and right numbers, but which value would "mid" refer to? How can I still extract each of the more central numbers?

Comment: The real question is: do you need to keep previous values when the RTD formula updates and shows new numbers? If no, then the solution can be a formula and the results can be split into cells as the data changes. But if you need to keep a history of previous values of the RTD function, then you need VBA to capture that and the whole approach of separating out the elements of the row will be totally different. Please clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:**

**Text to Column is not suitable for this since you are trying to split Comma Separated Values from the Formula Cell.**

**Note,**

*Text to Column can do this but it spoils the Formula.*

[image]

*So that better you try this formula, write it in an appropriate cell & fill Right & Down if required.*

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2, ",",  REPT(" ", 999)), (COLUMN(A:A)-1)*999+1, 999))
```

**Note,** *adjust cell references in formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution, and it would have worked in 2018 or 1998, would be to create a Named Range and set a formula in the `Refers to:`:

```
=EVALUATE(A1)
```

That assumes the data is pulled into A1 and that you have selected the cell you want the output in. If anything differs, edit accordingly. I used relative referencing ("A1" vs. "$A$1" or "A$1" or so on) so what cell you have selected when you paste that in matters, a lot.

In 2018, it might have been necessary to select all the cells you would need for output and enter the formula with `{CSE}` entry (<kbd>Ctrl-Shift-Enter</kbd>). In 2021, it will `SPILL` automatically.

`EVALUATE()` is from the Excel 4 Macro set. You CANNOT use it IN a cell directly. It must live in a Named Range that you refer to in the cell.

Because of this, and because it is very convoluted to use Named Ranges with parameters, you cannot use this to just "wrap" the `RTD()` function like you might wrap it with `LEFT()` or `IFERROR()` so you would need the =`Named Range` formula in a separate cell from it. But you want separate cells for the individual pieces of the input, so it seems you would not mind the extra columns being used.

However, you COULD Make the Named Range wrap the `RTD()` function if you have its parameters in cells somewhere that fit the pattern. (In the same up/down position as the current cell. So if your `RTD()`'s start in row 31 and run down 100 cells, the individual parameters or parameter sets take 100 contiguous column cells though their starting row could be very different. In any case, that would output the information without a column showing the CSV input material, just the split apart output.

Now, in November 2021, MS just announced that organizations can exclude Excel 4 Macros from their Excel seat Trust Centers. So after 30 years of working great, they may be going slowly away as some orgs will surely do that and people will start saying they don't work and, of course, not being willing to fight that battle with their org-masters. Ah well...

Excel had better add a cell-side formula that does what `EVALUATE()` does. `INDIRECT()` is NOT any kind of substitute for it. Been needed for decades, but we had to wait 15 years for `FORMULATEXT()` so we could stop using a different E4Macro command. I'll be dead in 15 years so I hope this one is quicker... Maybe `LAMBDA()` will do it b accident, sort of like `FILTERXML()` can create an array out of a string? It kinda looks so, but we'll see.

By the way, in `SPILL`-times, `EVALUATE()` does what `FILTERXML()` does for splitting a string, most cases, and a lot more simply.